# Unable to modify a fucntion from inside the function

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

I am trying to change variable (*state*) from *fun3* which is called from multiple function as shown in the *image*.
When i print *state* from inside fun3, it prints the modified variable *game*.**But when i print *state* from func1, it prints *menu*.**
Problem: it is not modifying the orignal variable in the file **game.py.**
I spent 3 hours to solve the problem but it is not solving.
If any one has the solution Please help in this problem.

Comment: A Python function does not modify its arguments (they are passed by value). Use the returned value instead.

Comment: Also, don't use globally defined variables like this. It will make your code much harder to understand.

Comment: could it be the func3() function you are calling before definition? try re_arranging func3() to be the first before func2().  I may also advise you to read about decorators "@" if you want to change function behaviour.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.